# How do I get multiple rows output in one line?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

The data is like Jane has items pen pencil eraser.

If I write the statement 'select * from item'
the output is:

```
Jane pen
Jane pencil
Jane eraser
Jack box
Jack wiper
```

I want the output to be like:

```
Jane pen pencil eraser
Jack box wiper
```

How to do this?

Comment: Does your item table have two columns?  Do you want your output to have two columns, one with the name and one with a space separated string of all the items they own?  If so, how would you handle items that include a space?  Or do you want your output to have 4 columns?  Or a dynamic number of columns depending on the input data?

Answer (score 4):

You can try as below:

```
SELECT name,
LISTAGG(item_name, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item_name) AS item_name 
FROM item 
GROUP BY name;
```