# How to print a query from many rows in one line?

Tags: t-sql

In SQL Server 2017, I have a many-to-many table:

```
=========================
id     nameID     phoneID
=========================
1        1           1
2        2           2
3        1           3
```

Let's say nameID 1 is FK for John in a NameTable. phoneID 1 is FK in PhoneTable for 01 234 567 and phoneID 3 is FK for 02 345 678.

When I `join` tables I get two rows.

```
======================
name        phone
======================
John       01 234 567
John       02 345 678
```

However, I need a string in one line. How do I print name and phones in one line like this:

```
John, 01 234 567, 02 345 678
```

Edit1: I found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141059/how-do-i-get-multiple-rows-output-in-one-line) similar question and solution for Oracle with `LISTAGG`.
Edit2: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) is a solution for T-SQL with `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: A `join` may be?

Comment: Of course join is needed. The problem is I get two rows and I need all in one line.

Comment: You forgot the link to the T-SQL `FOR XML PATH` solution. And, if that works, why not use it?

Comment: Well, I just found it. That is why it is called 'edit question'. I will use it when I test it and if it's an answer I'll post it.

Comment: How are you going to join 1 to 'John' or '02 345 678'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your SQL Server version. In SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can use STRING_AGG:

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, FirstName VARCHAR(25))
DECLARE @Phones TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Phone VARCHAR(25))
DECLARE @ManyToMany TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, NameID INT, PhoneID INT)

INSERT INTO @Names 
VALUES ('John'), ('Mike')

INSERT INTO @Phones 
VALUES ('12 345 678'), ('00 987 654'), ('11 254 009')

INSERT INTO @ManyToMany (NameID, PhoneID)
VALUES (1, 1), -- John link #1
    (1, 3), --John link #2
    (2, 2) -- Mike link #1

SELECT n.FirstName AS [Name],
    STRING_AGG(p.[Phone], ',') AS [Phone]
FROM @ManyToMany m
INNER JOIN @Names n ON n.ID = m.NameID
LEFT JOIN @Phones p ON p.ID = m.PhoneID
GROUP BY n.FirstName
```

Results:

```
Name    Phone
-----------------------------
John    12 345 678,11 254 009
Mike    00 987 654
```